# morphosyntax meaning

Tags: meaning, grammar, linguistics

I know that "Morphosyntax is the study of the interaction of morphology and syntax" but by this defination am not getting the meaning so please can anyone tell me what is morphosyntax with examples?

Answer (score 2):

[*Morphology*](http://www.personal.uni-jena.de/~x4diho/Morphosyntax.Introduction.pdf) is the study of the structure of words, in particular the analysis of their parts with respect to meaning.  For instance in the sentence

> One dog is a pet; many dogs are a pack

the fact that the plural of *dog* is formed by added a final *-s* is a morphological consideration.  [*Syntax*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20syntax) is the study of the structure of sentences, i.e., the rules that dictate how meaningful thoughts are expressed in a string of words.

In the sentence above, note the syntactical consideration that requires a singular verb (*is*) to go with the singular subject (*One dog*), but a plural verb (*are*) to go with the plural subject (*many dogs*).

Comment: but what about morphosyntax? With some examples

Comment: morphology+syntax=morphosyntax??

Comment: @madan Of course.  You even state in your question that morphosyntax is "the interaction of morphology and syntax."  The former comes from the Greek word for form; the latter, from the Greek word for arrangement.  The study of  forms of words and their arrangement in sentences is pretty much grammar (or morphosyntax, if you prefer).  Do I need to repeat your assertion in the example? As for examples, what did you find lacking in the *dog* example in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Deadrat has explained very well what morphology is, the form or internal structure of a word, and what syntax is, the structure of a sentence or the conexions between words.

The distinction between morphology and syntax is often useful, but sometimes it is unclear or counter-productive. For that reason, it is sometimes more useful to see morphology and syntax as two extremes of a continuum, two aspects of a single body of linguistic analysis. That single body is then called **morphosyntax**. Below I offer a few examples of when it makes less sense to threat the two as separate things.

---

The distinction depends heavily on the assumption of word barriers, that it is clear where a word begins and where it ends. But that is not always clear. There are languages where verbs and nouns can be written together as one word, and they may or may not have a single word accent. Does that mean it is a single word, and that you shouldn't be applying any laws of syntax or comparing it with sentences in other languages?

Consider English *wasn't*. Is this a single word, where *-n't* is a negative suffix? Suffixes are part of morphology. Or is it two words written attached? The relation between two words is part of syntax. Or: is it even useful to distinguish between those two models?

Consider also enclitics. Those are small words that are generally written with a space in between it and another word, but they do not have their own word accent. In Greek, for example, one often writes the word *moi* "me" (dative) after another word as an enclitic, where the two words together form a phonological unit. Should those two be considered a single word or not?

The mere existence of a space in typography is but a convention. In Mediaeval and Ancient writing, spaces were often not used. And the rules of spatiation often change. For example, *house door* is written with a space, but the Dutch aequivalent *huisdeur* is written attached. Does that mean those two should be analysed in completely different ways? Or is the word boundary or lack thereof in this case insignificant?